# Python Combination with Condition and Multiple criteria

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, combinations

I have 3 **lists** of different lengths

**a = [ 945, 625, 800, 146, 12, 84]**

**b = [ 0, 1, 4, 249, 84.3, 87, 98, 128, 872, 973, 674, 1238, 897]**

**c = [24, 36, 84, 23]**

I want to create a ***combination of 3 elements*** through the following criteria:

1. The output should **not** have **elements at the same index**.

   ex- **a [0], b [0], c [0] or (945,0,24) is invalid**.
2. A 3-number combination should have **a one digit number, a two-digit number 
   and a three-digit number**.

   **Thus, (945,0,23) is valid while (945,128,24) is incorrect.**
3. How can I place some criteria to **eliminate combination containing all even or all odd numbers**?
   **Therefore, (146,1,23) and (800,4,84) both are incorrect**.
4. How can I place a **floor and ceiling criteria in combination**? For example – The maximum number cannot be more than 100 times the minimum number.

   Therefore **(800,4,23) would be incorrect because 800 is more than 100 times the minimum number i.e. 4**

Comment: Is this homework ? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried combination using itertools but could not proceed with the criteria. While generating combinations I am putting floor and ceiling which is static which generates combinations within the floor and ceiling and not a value which is dynamic.

Comment: combo = (x, y, z) for x in a and y in b and z in c and num < x > num and num <y>num and num <z>num

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to use `product` to get cartesian product of the list, and then write four filter functions to do this:

```
a = [945, 625, 800, 146, 12, 84]
b = [0, 1, 4, 249, 84.3, 87, 98, 128, 872, 973, 674, 1238, 897]
c = [24, 36, 84, 23]

from itertools import product

c1 = lambda x: x not in zip(a, b, c)
c2 = lambda x: {len(str(i)) for i in x}=={1,2,3}
c3 = lambda x: not (all(i % 2 == 0 for i in x) or all(i % 2 != 0 for i in x))
c4 = lambda x: max(x) < 100 * min(x)

r1 = filter(c1,product(a,b,c))

r2 = filter(c2,r1)

r3 = filter(c3,r2)

r4 = filter(c4,r3)
print(r4)
```

So the expected output is:

```
(146, 4, 23)
```